# How to round to the next largest number?

Tags: javascript, math

I want my number to always get rounded up to the closest number like this:

> 1.2 => **2**
>
> 1.4 => **2**
>
> 2.5 => **3**
>
> 2.9 => **3**

How can i do this with JavaScript?

Answer (score 152, accepted):

You can use the `Math.ceil()` function.

```
Math.ceil(1.1) // returns 2
```

Conversely, if you wanted to round *down* you'd use `Math.floor()`

```
Math.floor(1.8) // returns 1
```

Here's a demo:

```js
const input = [1, 0.5, 0.49, 0, -0.5, -0.51,  -1];
const ops = ["floor", "ceil", "round"];
const output = input.map(n =>
  ops.reduce((record, op) => {
    record[`Math.${op}(n)`] = Math[op](n);
    return record;
  }, {n}));
console.table(output);
```

```html
<script src="https://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script><script>console.config({maximize:true,timeStamps:false})</script><style>.as-console-wrapper{display:block;}</style>
```

<sub>Note: Floor and ceiling functions aren't exclusive to javascript. See this [wikipedia entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) for more info.</sub>

Answer (score 10):

Use [`Math.ceil()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/ceil):

```
Math.ceil(1.2); // 2
```

Answer (score 9):

Use `Math.ceil()`

It does exactly what you want.

Answer (score -1):

I use `Math.ceil()` function for round upper value.