# Dividing and rounding up

Tags: javascript, jquery, math

How can i dividing and rounding up in javascript?
For example:

```
var one = 10/4;
```

This return 2.5, but i would like receive 3

```
var two = 120/7;
```

This return 17.14, but i would like receive 18

etc

How is the best way for this?

Comment: Ever heard about `Math.ceil()` and `Math.floor()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [javascript round always to upper number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11194831/javascript-round-always-to-upper-number)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to round up a number in Javascript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5191088/how-to-round-up-a-number-in-javascript)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `Math.ceil`:

```
Math.ceil(10/4); //3
```